# Trying to convert str object to DataFrame: web scraping with python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, web-scraping, split

**System:** WIN10

**IDE:** MS VSCode

**Language:** Python version 3.7.3

**Library:** pandas version 1.0.1

**Data source:** https://hoopshype.com/salaries/#hh-tab-team-payroll

**Dataset:** team payrolls

I am having an issue for some reason when trying to convert a str(table) into a dataframe.  I think I am grossly missing something here. The sample code is supplied below and it keeps throwing only the top row of data into the data frame. I think I am missing some other transformation process.

**Steps were taken:**

1. searched the net for various tutorials
2. tried splitting the data first then trying the conversion on it to no luck

**Code:**

```
    # import Libraries

    import pandas as pd
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from tabulate import tabulate

    # data visualization
    import matplotlib as plt
    import seaborn as sns

    # setting: For output purposes to show all columns
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
    pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 2000)
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)
    pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

    # parsing the webpage
    url = 'https://hoopshype.com/salaries/#hh-tab-team-payroll'
    r = requests.get(url)
    data = r.text

    # create a beautfulsoup object
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'lxml')
    soup.prettify

    # team salaries by year = tsby
    table = soup.find_all('table')[0]
    nbatsby = pd.read_html(str(table))

    # this is where I am stuck
    df = pd.DataFrame(nbatsby)
    df.head(100)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pandas has [`read_html`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html) which can scrape an html table an convert it to dataframe directly :

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

r = requests.get("https://hoopshype.com/salaries/#hh-tab-team-payroll")
data = pd.read_html(r.text, attrs = {'class': 'hh-salaries-ranking-table'})[0]

print(data)
```

Output:

```
    Unnamed: 0           Team       2019/20       2020/21       2021/22       2022/23      2023/24      2024/25
0          1.0       Portland  $XXX,XXX,XXX  $XXXX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX  $XX,XXX,XXX  $XX,XXX,XXX
1          2.0          Miami  $XXX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX           $0           $0
................................................................................................................
28        29.0        Indiana  $XXX,XXX,XXX  $XXX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX  $XX,XXX,XXX           $0
29        30.0       New York  $XXX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX   $XX,XXX,XXX            $0           $0           $0
```

Comment: This worked fantastically. I am still researching the point of using {beautiful soup: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/, and or scrapy: https://scrapy.org/}

Comment: @AlfredHull In fact, pandas [use beautifulsoup under the hood](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/467e1c208f58effb62d983a1f455eb10aea629c3/pandas/io/html.py) if installed

Comment: that explains it: I was wondering why that works so well. It is almost a hidden gem for at least scraping data tables from the web.